# Selenium Java - Copy Image from URL to clipboard and Paste it as image

Tags: java, selenium

I want to copy image/gif from URL without download it,
for example, I want to copy this gif to clipboard  https://media.giphy.com/media/l49JL8rJ2vOEXlmM0/giphy.gif
and paste this gif to this site
https://paste.pics/

I tried everything but it's not working.

Code trials :
Copy to clipboard :

```
StringSelection data = new StringSelection ("https://media.giphy.com/media/xThtap5F0MFyAkoBPi/giphy.gif"); 
Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard(); 
cb.setContents(data, data);
```

Paste 1

```
try {
        Transferable t = cb.getContents(null);
        if (t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor))
            System.out.println(t.getTransferData(DataFlavor
                    .stringFlavor));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("elementFromSite")).sendKeys(t.getTransferData(DataFlavor
                .imageFlavor).toString());
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("issue");
    }
```

Paste 2

```
driver.findElement(By.id(elementFromSite)).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"v"));
```

so I don't have any idea how can I achieve it 
Please assist

Comment: can you share what you have tried?

Comment: You should edit it in as I did...

Comment: Which part isn't working?  Is it copying to the clipboard successfully and not pasting, or does it not get it on the clipboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I would try:

```
driver.get("https://media.giphy.com/media/l49JL8rJ2vOEXlmM0/giphy.gif");
driver.find_by_css_selector('a._3X9Zhs_atixoQRBDsNGQnl > img').sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+ "c");

driver.get("https://paste.pics/");
Actions action = new Actions(driver); 

action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("v").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
```

If that doesn't work you could try doing ctrl+v on an element on the page, like

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('whatever selector you want to target some element on the page').sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+ "v");
```

Does that help at all?

Comment: No:Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <img src=""> is not reachable by keyboard